# How do I access bottle development server from another PC on the LAN?

Tags: python, windows, web-services, bottle

I'm running the bottle.py tutorial on one PC, and I was able to access it using

```
http://localhost:8080/hello/world
```

However, when I tried to access it (IP address is 192.168.1.10) from another PC on the LAN, using

```
http://192.168.1.10:8080/hello/world
```

I received the "Cannot Open Page" error.

I have the Apache web server running on the PC, and I can access the web server without any problem using

```
http://192.168.1.10
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the [Quickstart: “Hello World”](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#quickstart-hello-world) example:

Change this line:

```
run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

To bind to the public IPv4 address of your computer:

```
run(host='192.168.1.10', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Or to this to listen on all interfaces including the external one [**Source**: [`bottle.run`, Bottle API Reference](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.run)]:

```
run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Then you should be able to access `http://192.168.1.10:8080/hello/world` from your local PC as well as another PC on the LAN. Alternatively use a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN).

If connections are still refused, check your firewall settings.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Would this method also work if you want someone to check the webserver via the internet?  ( I can't check via the internet at the moment)